# Apache rewrite rule 403 error

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, http-status-code-403

I'm running Apache 2.2.15 with rewrite_module installed. I have rule in my vhost.conf as follows;

```
RewriteRule \n
    ^/advanced/selector/profiles/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ \n
    "/advanced/selector/profiles/rewrite.cfm?path=$1" [L]
```

This should capture the path which doesn't exist and redirect the request to the rewrite.cfm file (the only file in the ../profiles/ folder) with the capture group as the URL.path param. However, I'm currently getting a 403 error instead. My server access log is logging the 403 but my error log is not.

```
devserver.mydomain.co.uk - - - [25/Jan/2016:12:17:47 +0000] "GET /advanced/selector/profiles/FirstYearAllowance HTTP/1.1" 403 95 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
```

Happy to post any more detail if there's useful information I've neglected to include. I'd be really grateful if someone could advise me how to get this working!